# Prove the limit of an IVP is zero.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

> Let $U\in\mathbb{R}^d$ be open and let $F\in C^1(U, \mathbb{R}^d)$. Fix $p\in U$. Consider the IVP
> $$
> \dot{x}=F(x),\ x(0)=p
> $$
> Let $(T_-, T_+)$ be the maximal interval be the maximal interval of existence. Assume
> $$
> \lim_{t\uparrow T_+}x(t)=\zeta\in U
> $$
> Prove that $F(\zeta)=0$.

I just learned the extensibility of solution and have difficulty in working out the answer. However, by the extensibility theory, it seems $T_+$ has to be $+\infty$. Do I mistaken something? Please give a concrete explaination.

Any hint or answer of the original question could be very helpful!

Comment: That's a correct implication of general facts about the extensibility of solutions. If $T_+$ were finite, you could solve the IVP with initial data $x(T_+) = \zeta$ on a small interval $ (T_+ - \delta, T_+ + \delta)$ and this solution would have to agree with the given one on $(T_+-\delta, T_+)$ by continuity. Thus $T_+$ would not be maximal.

Comment: Yes, I did the same work, but it seems unrelavant to the conclusion of the original problem, at least I haven't see the connection. I just wonder why not write $T_+$ as $+\infty$ directly. Please give some help in proving the original problem. Thanks.

Comment: You know that $x(t)$ has a limit, so $F(x(t))$ also has a limit, and therefore $\dot{x}(t)$ must have the same limit. Now assume that that limit is $\ne 0$. Is that possible?

Comment: $T_+=\infty$ because $(t,x(t))$ must leave every compact set  of $(\mathbb R\times U)$ as $t\uparrow T_+$ so the limit cannot be properly contained in $U$.